# Finding bioperl on cpanmetadb failed

Tags: software-installation, perl

I failed to install bioperl on debian in the following way:

```
$ sudo cpanm bioperl
! Finding bioperl on cpanmetadb failed.
! Finding bioperl () on mirror http://www.cpan.org failed.
! Couldn't find module or a distribution bioperl
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: `conda install -c bioconda perl-bioperl`  instead of using CPAN